# Is it possible to change the download filename when serving with static handler?

Tags: erlang, cowboy

When serving a file in cowboy2, using a static file handler, is it possible to have the "download" filename be different from the actual filename on disk?

For example, let's say I'm serving static file "123". When the user downloads it in the browser, is it possible to have it come out as "123.txt"?

Because right now, all my filenames get automatically assigned a filename with ".dms" extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the normal operation of a static handler is to return files that your browser downloads.

> When the static handler fails to [recognize] the extension, it will
>   send the file as application/octet-stream. A browser receiving such
>   file will attempt to download it directly to disk.

Backing up a little, an http response almost always includes a `Content-Type` header, which specifies the type of the content being sent to the browser so that the browser knows how to display the content.  The type of the content is specified with a `mime type`.  A response containing a typical html page has a Content-Type header that looks like this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

The `text/html` mime type tells the browser not to display the file as text but instead *render* the text as html.

Cowboy looks at the requested file's extension to determine what mime type to specify in the Content-Type header in the response.  If a file doesn't have an extension, then Cowboy specifies the mime type as `application/octet-stream`, which causes your browser to download the file.  Your browser basically says, "I have no idea how to display this binary data, so here, you take the file and figure out what to do with it."

If all your files without extensions are (plain) text files, then you can tell cowboy to set a mime type of `text/plain` for all the files matching a route:

hello_erlang/src/hello_erlang_app.erl:

```
-module(hello_erlang_app).
-behaviour(application).

-export([start/2]).
-export([stop/1]).

start(_Type, _Args) ->
    Dispatch = cowboy_router:compile([
        {'_', [
               {"/dog/[...]", cowboy_static, 
                    {
                        priv_dir, 
                        hello_erlang, 
                        "static/assets", 
                        [{mimetypes, {<<"text">>, <<"plain">>, []} }] %<**HERE
                    }
               },

               {"/please_upgrade_to_websocket", myws_handler, []} 
        ]}
    ]),

    {ok, _} = cowboy:start_clear(my_http_listener,
        [{port, 8080}],
        #{env => #{dispatch => Dispatch} }
    ),

    hello_erlang_sup:start_link().

stop(_State) ->
    ok.
```

Mime types use the syntax `word1/word2`, and cowboy takes what you specify here:

```
[{mimetypes, {<<"text">>, <<"plain">>, []} }]
```

and joins the two words with a forward slash to produce "text/plain" for the mime type.

Directory structure:

```
hello_erlang/priv/static/assets/
    file1
    file2
    file3
```

url:

```
http://localhost:8080/dog/file1
```

You can also tell cowboy to call a custom function to set the mime types of your files:

hello_erlang/src/hello_erlang_app.erl:

```
-module(hello_erlang_app).
-behaviour(application).

-export([start/2]).
-export([stop/1]).

start(_Type, _Args) ->
    Dispatch = cowboy_router:compile([
        {'_', [
               {"/dog/[...]", cowboy_static, 
                    {
                        priv_dir, 
                        hello_erlang, 
                        "static/assets", 
                        [{mimetypes, my_mime_setter, set_type}] %<** HERE  {mimetypes, MODULE, FUNCTION}
                    }
               },

               {"/please_upgrade_to_websocket", myws_handler, []} 
        ]}
    ]),

    {ok, _} = cowboy:start_clear(my_http_listener,
        [{port, 8080}],
        #{env => #{dispatch => Dispatch} }
    ),

    hello_erlang_sup:start_link().

stop(_State) ->
    ok.
```

hello_erlang/src/my_mime_setter.erl:

```
-module(my_mime_setter).
-export([set_type/1]).

set_type(Path) ->
    Fname = filename:basename(Path),
    TextFiles = [<<"file1">>, <<"file2">>],

    case filename:extension(Fname) of
        <<>> ->  %no extension found(Yeah, I thought this would be an empty list, too!)
            case lists:member(Fname, TextFiles) of
                true  -> {<<"text">>, <<"plain">>, []};
                false -> {<<"text">>, <<"html">>, []}
            end;

        Ext ->
            case Ext of 
                <<".html">> -> {<<"text">>, <<"html">>, []};
                <<".css">>  -> {<<"text">>, <<"css">>, []};
                <<".js">>   -> {<<"application">>, <<"javascript">>, []};
                _Other      -> {<<"application">>, <<"octet-stream">>, []}
            end
    end.
```

You can test the custom mime setter with these files:

hello_erlang/priv/static/assets/file1:

```
<div><font color="red">red text</font></div>
```

hello_erlang/priv/static/assets/file4:

```
<div><font color="red">red text</font></div>
```

If you request the first file:

```
http://localhost:8080/dog/file1
```

the mime type will get set to `text/plain`, and the browser won't render the html, instead you'll see the raw html.  If you request the second file:

```
http://localhost:8080/dog/file4
```

the mime type will get set to `text/html`, which will cause the browser to render the text, and you should see some red text.

If you want to punt on the files that do have extensions, you can write:

```
   _Ext ->
       cow_mimetypes:web(Fname)
```

and cowboy will use its algorithm to come up with a mime type.